# How to set emacs line color based on start character

Tags: emacs

I use emacs day to day, but I'm not a lisp expert. How can I define a simple mode to color the lines in a buffer according to the first character?

e.g. if it's an 'p' then text is green, if it's an 'i' then the text is red. ... I have about about half a dozen rules I would like to define.

This mode only applies to a very specific text file, I obviously don't need functionality in other situations!

Thanks,

Comment: Check M-x highlight-regexp use: ^p.*$ (for p starting lines).   It doesn't changes the color, but highlights line.   Non-interactively (highlight-regexp "^p.*$" (quote hi-green))  Put bunch of such statement in function and run that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out; but I need this more dynamic, i.e. to re-colour the lines if I change the initial letter, i.e. syntax colouring in programming modes.

Comment: http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_define_face.html  may be useful.

Comment: Thank you, that was just what I needed. See answer below

Comment: @aartist How come it is necessary to write (quote hi-green) instead of "hi-green"? This fixed my earlier attempt using highlight-lines-matching-regexp,: (highlight-lines-matching-regexp "%y" (quote hi-yellow))

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to aartist, here is what I ended up with

```
(defface mymode-q '((t :foreground "red" )) "" )
(defface mymode-p '((t :foreground "green" )) "" )
(defface mymode-i '((t :foreground "yellow" )) "" )
(defface mymode-r '((t :foreground "blue" )) "" )
(defface mymode-c '((t :foreground "orange" )) "" )
(defface mymode-x '((t :foreground "grey50" )) "" )

(setq mymode-highlights '(
    ("^q .*$" . 'mymode-q)
    ("^p .*$" . 'mymode-p)
    ("^i .*$" . 'mymode-i)
    ("^r .*$" . 'mymode-r)
    ("^c .*$" . 'mymode-c)
    ("^x .*$" . 'mymode-x)
    ))

(define-derived-mode mymode-mode text-mode "mymode" "major mode mymode."
    (setq font-lock-defaults '(mymode-highlights)))
```

Comment: It's very cool. Thanks Dave for posting. I will make  use your code in my writing. Especially while taking the meeting notes.  I am thinking about more uses for this.